# sql error: Unknown column in 'field list' on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I am trying to insert an entry into a table, using Java, and it returns me an error "Unknown column XX in 'field list'".

For example: I have created a table using this line:

```
CREATE  TABLE `dbcs`.`born in` (`person` VARCHAR(100) ,`year` INT ,`prob` FLOAT);
```

the table was created successfully.

when I try to insert something to the table, it shows me the error. for example, the command:

```
INSERT INTO `dbcs`.`born in` VALUES (`Alanis Morissette`,1974,1.0)
```

will generate the error:

> Unknown column 'Alanis Morissette' in 'field list'

Comment: Delimit String values with quotes i.e.  INSERT INTO dbcs.born in VALUES ('Alanis Morissette',1974,1.0)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Strings must be wrapped in quotes. You're using ticks which are not correct.

```
INSERT INTO `dbcs`.`born in` VALUES ('Alanis Morissette',1974,1.0)
```

Comment: I think you need some backticks around `born in`. Also, I would emphasize that backticks should be used for system names.

Comment: @Kermit I would have also added don't use spaces in names and avoid using a reserved keyword as a table/column name unless you really want to annoy somebody :-)

Comment: @Endophage In the table name, yes.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
INSERT INTO dbcs.born in VALUES ('Alanis Morissette',1974,1.0)
```